# __attribute__((naked)) doesn't work

Tags: arm, clang

I think this is some configuration issues. The target is armv7.

The function is

```
__attribute__((naked))
id new_objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...) {
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("nop\n");
}
```

And the generated code is

```
Dump of assembler code for function _Z16new_objc_msgSendP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorz:
0x01bc7dfc <_Z16new_objc_msgSendP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorz+0>: stmia.w sp, {r2, r3}
0x01bc7e00 <_Z16new_objc_msgSendP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorz+4>: nop
0x01bc7e02 <_Z16new_objc_msgSendP11objc_objectP13objc_selectorz+6>: bx  lr
End of assembler dump.
```

Even with `__attribute__((naked))`, prolog/epilog is still generated.

Comment: I see no epilog there, and that "prolog" looks to be (at a guess) a consequence of varargs, not a regular function entry. How does a function with fixed arguments come out?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. For a regular function. The generated code is
`Dump of assembler code for function _Z3cccv:
0x01c04df8 <_Z3cccv+0>: nop
0x01c04dfa <_Z3cccv+2>: bx lr
End of assembler dump.`
But is there a way to remove line 1 and 3 in the post?

Comment: I'd say the return is a fundamental part of the function, rather than part of the epilog. Without it, you'd just be left with a goto, not a function.

Comment: Thx. The epilog added by the compiler does not matter since I can branch to the desired place if I don't want to use the generated one.